# changing the Jenkins pipeline to use password parameter or Credentials parameter instead od Hudson password

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-cli

Below is the pipeline script for my job:

```groovy
pipeline {
    agent any
  
    stages {
        stage('Runbook database deploy job') {
            steps {          
                withCredentials([
                    usernamePassword(credentialsId: 'RUNBOOK_RDS_DBADMIN', passwordVariable: 'DB_APPTEAM_PASS', usernameVariable: 'DB_APPTEAM_USER'),
                    usernamePassword(credentialsId: 'nexus_download_user', passwordVariable: 'NEXUS_APPTEAM_PASS', usernameVariable: 'NEXUS_APPTEAM_USER')
                ]) {
                build job: 'DBA-TSS/db_aurora-mysql_DEPLOY/', parameters: [
                    string(name: 'INSTALL_TYPE', value: "${INSTALL_TYPE}"),
                    string(name: 'SDLC', value: "${SDLC}"),
                    string(name: 'DB_ARTIFACT', value: "${DB_ARTIFACT}"),
                    string(name: 'DEV_NEXUS_ID', value: NEXUS_APPTEAM_USER),
                    [$class: 'hudson.model.PasswordParameterValue', name: 'DEV_NEXUS_PASSWORD', value:hudson.util.Secret.fromString(NEXUS_APPTEAM_PASS)],                               
                    string(name: 'DEV_NEXUS_REPO', value: "${DEV_NEXUS_REPO}"),
                    string(name: 'DB_USERNAME', value: DB_APPTEAM_USER),
                    [$class: 'hudson.model.PasswordParameterValue', name: 'DB_PASSWORD', value:hudson.util.Secret.fromString(DB_APPTEAM_PASS)],                             
                    string(name: 'REQUESTER_EMAIL', value: "${REQUESTER_EMAIL}")                                  
                ]}
            }
        }     
    }
}
```

And now as hudson is not supported , we want to replace it with Credentials id or password parameter to pass it to downstream job for password variable. can you please help us on this.

Comment: Looks lime what's been deprecated is [PasswordParameterValue(String name, String value, String description)](https://javadoc.jenkins.io/hudson/model/PasswordParameterValue.html#PasswordParameterValue-java.lang.String-hudson.util.Secret-java.lang.String-); use PasswordParameterValue(String name, **Secret value**, String description)

Comment: What parameter type is your downstream job expecting?